# Union 60 Dataframes in palantir foundry directory using pyspark

Tags: pyspark, palantir-foundry

I have a directory with 60+ foundry dataset in it. I just to read all the datasets and union it into a single dataframe

Path = input("MySpend new files P2P/2020/")

```
Dataset1
Dataset2
Dataset3
...
Dataset60
```

Output("MySpend new files P2P/2020/UnionAll")

Comment: Hi Biplab1985 any chance you could better formulate your question? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask I think I know what you want, and don't mind dropping an example, but all stackoverflow community would benefit for a properly formulated question, instead of a statement, like above.

Answer (score 1):

More technically :

- You can leverage `union_many` in your transform (more verbose [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72883911/how-to-union-several-datasets-with-the-same-schema-in-palantir-foundry)) and list its inputs manually. Note that you can use Data Lineage to quickly copy paste the paths of all the datasets (`select datasets > top right > "view histogram" icon > "copy paths"`). Basic usage :

```py
from transforms.api import transform_df, Input, Output
from transforms.verbs import dataframes as D

@transform_df(
    Output("/path/to/dataset/unioned"),
    source_df_1=Input("/path/to/dataset/one"),
    source_df_2=Input("/path/to/dataset/two"),
    source_df_3=Input("/path/to/dataset/three"),
)
def compute(source_df_1, source_df_2, source_df_3):
    return D.union_many(
        source_df_1,
        source_df_2,
        source_df_3,
    )
```

- Same way but easier to copy paste, you can parameter your transform to use an array of paths as an input

```py
from transforms.verbs import dataframes as D
from transforms.api import transform_df, Input, Output

# Configure the number of datasets to generate
list_datasets_paths = [
    "/path/to/dataset/one",
    "/path/to/dataset/two",
    "/path/to/dataset/three"]


# Convert the list of paths in a dict of Input()
input_dict = {}
for dataset_path in list_datasets_paths:
    input_dict[dataset_path.split("/")[-1]] = Input(dataset_path)


# Provide the dict of Input() to the transform
@transform_df(
    Output("/path/to/dataset/unioned"),
    **input_dict
)
def compute_2(**inputs_dataframes):
    # Create a list of dataframes from the input dict
    dataframes_list = inputs_dataframes.values()
    # Union the list of dataframes
    return D.union_many(*dataframes_list)
```

- If the set of dataset were to evolve over time, you can use [Logic Flows](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/building-pipelines/compass-file-lister/). It will essentially list rids (resource identifiers) of resources in a given input folder and open a new pull request the repository with a file containing those rids/paths. Note this is a beta product.

Note: You have as well other tools to build pipeline, and hence union datasets, like [Pipeline Builder](https://www.palantir.com/platforms/foundry/whatsnew/pipeline-builder/)/[docs](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/pipeline-builder/overview/).